# How is this function closed?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am reading appendix of convex optimization book. In example A.1 it is written that $$f(x)=\array{x\log(x)\quad \text{if}\quad  x>0 \quad \text{and}\quad  0 \quad \text{if} \quad x=0}$$ Its domain is $[0,\infty)$. Now function is continuous. The boundary of the domain is empty set (please point out if I am wrong in this). So since the empty set is subset of every set therefore the domain of $f$ is closed. But at the same time since the intersection of every set and empty set is an empty set therefore the domain of $f$ is open. So if the domain is closed then the function $f$ is closed but in this case the domain is also open so I do not understand how $f$ is closed. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you say the boundary is the empty set?

Comment: @Daniel domain of $f$ is $[0,\infty)$. Now $int(R \text{minus} dom f)=(-\infty ,0)$. Further closure of domain of $f$ is $R \text{minus} int (R \text{minus} dom f)=[0,\infty )=[0,\infty)$. And the boundary of domain of $f$ is closure of domain of $f$ minus the domain of $f$ which is empty set. Please point if I am wrong.

Comment: $0$ is a boundary point, right? So I'm not quite getting your argument. Anyway, it's fairly easy to see that the domain is closed (as I think you're concluding), so just because of that and the fact that $f$ is continuous, the function is closed. It doesn't matter whether or not the domain is open or anything else

Comment: Even if the domain were open (which it isn't) why would you think that would mean the function isn't closed?  Open and closed are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundary of your domain is the boundary of $[0, \infty ]$ which is ${\text { {0}}}$ which is a closed set.

Your domain is closed because it includes its boundary. It is not open because there is no open interval centered at $0$ which is contained entirely in the domain.

Comment: a union of two intervals e.g. $[0,1] U [2,+\infty)$ is a closed set?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The boundary of the domain is the set $\{0\}$. Every open ball centered at zero intersects $[0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)=\mathbb{R}\setminus [0,\infty)$. Moreover, the set $[0,\infty)$ is closed. Take a point $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus [0,\infty)$, then, if $\varepsilon=\dfrac{|x|}{2}$ then $B_\varepsilon(x)\subseteq\mathbb{R}\setminus [0,\infty)$, i.e., $\mathbb{R}\setminus [0,\infty)$ is open, thus, $[0,\infty)$ is closed.

The previous arguments holds if your whole space is $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology. But if your whole space is $[0,\infty)$ then you're correct: the boundary is the empty set and $[0,\infty)$ is open and closed.

Finally, the closed-ness of the open-ness of your function doesn't follows from the properties of the domain (to be closed, for example). Do you have the correct definitions of closed and open function?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used the definition which is provided in convex optimization book (by Stephen Boyd) on page 640 line number 3. Which says that a function is closed if the function is continuous and the domain is closed. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I thought in the topological definition of a closed function: a function $f:X\to Y$ is closed if for all $A\subseteq X$ closed then $f[A]$ is closed. But, yes, you're right with the closed-ness of the function using the definition that you provides.